# SQL Query to find out common relationships from a given set of data

Tags: sql

Table: **friendship**

| userid_1 | userid_2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 7 |
| 4 | 6 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 5 | 7 |
| 6 | 7 |

From the above table, i want to find the count of relationships(userid_2) that are common for userid_1. Below is the sample output.

**Output:**

| userid_1 | common_userid |
| --- | --- |
| 1, 3 | 4 |
| 2,5,6 | 7 |

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Comment: look at this https://sqlperformance.com/2014/08/t-sql-queries/sql-server-grouped-concatenation

Comment: Please tag the specific DBMS you are using, so it will help to reach the question to get an answer for your specific DBMS.

Answer (score 4):

If your dbms is sql server or postgresql then you can use `string_agg()` with `group by` clause

Schema and insert statements:

```
 create table users(userid_1 int, userid_2 int)
 insert into users values(1,    4);
 insert into users values(2,    7);
 insert into users values(4,    6);
 insert into users values(3,    4);
 insert into users values(5,    7);
 insert into users values(6,    7);
```

Query for sql server:

```
 select string_agg(userid_1,',') userid_1,userid_2 common_userid 
 from users
 group by userid_2
 having count(userid_1)>1
```

Output:

| userid_1 | common_userid |
| --- | --- |
| 1,3 | 4 |
| 5,6,2 | 7 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=fa41baa742b537b61fe59e16f6cd1de4)*

Query for postgresql:

```
 select string_agg(userid_1::varchar,',' order by userid_1) userid_1,userid_2 common_userid 
 from users
 group by userid_2
 having count(userid_1)>1
```

Output:

| userid_1 | common_userid |
| --- | --- |
| 1,3 | 4 |
| 2,5,6 | 7 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=16552fc82292e4392f9633188652cf94)*

Comment: If this answer helped you please accept it as an answer so that the question can be marked as answered.

Answer (score 3):

you can do something like this if you are using MySQL

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(userid_1) as userid_1, userid_2 as common_userid FROM TableName GROUP BY userid_2 HAVING userid_1 > 1
```

if you can specify the database, I might be able to write you even an specific sql

Comment: Good answer, but could you please add the condition "HAVING COUNT(userid_1)>1"? Otherwise, also userid_1 = 4 will be selected what is not intended.

Answer (score 1):

Since you already got answers for MYSQL, Postgres and SQL Server DB, let's add a query for Oracle DB, too. You can use `LISTAGG` for that:

```
SELECT LISTAGG(userid_1,',')  AS userid_1,
userid_2 AS common_userid
FROM friendship
GROUP BY userid_2
HAVING COUNT(userid_1)>1
ORDER BY userid_1
```

The sorting can also be applied using `WITHIN GROUP` instead of at the end of the query:

```
SELECT LISTAGG(userid_1,',') 
WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY userid_1) AS userid_1,
userid_2 AS common_userid
FROM friendship
GROUP BY userid_2
HAVING COUNT(userid_1)>1
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=76d2e2d0215ddf2394861ae6042cbfae)

Comment: Query 2 is even ANSI SQL compliant, i.e. _expected_ to be more or less portable. (Optional features.)